# What's C calling convention standard?

Tags: c, linux, x86, system-calls, calling-convention

I'm writing a compiler and I'm trying to implement a C interface. So, I wrote a simple C program and saw the assembly code generated by GCC:

```
    ...

    mov rdi, rax
    call    puts@PL

    ....
```

I was expecting C to pass arguments to `puts` through the stack, but it uses the `di` register to do so. I tested other `libc`'s functions such as `sleep` and `calloc` and they all use registers as well.

So, is there a pattern for this? i.e. Do all `libc`'s functions receive arguments like syscalls?
And, where does C use the stack for function arguments? Is it only for user defined functions?

Comment: The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) goes over it.

Comment: And it is different on Linux and on Windows or on FreeBSD. For inspiration, study the source code of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC. **BTW did you consider [*generating C code*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) in your compiler, or using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) as the backend of your compiler ?**